# R For Loop Using List of Multiple Dataframes And Calling A Specific Column From These Dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, list, for-loop

I've been struggling to find an answer to this (hopefully) simple question.

So I have a list that includes multiple dataframes that all have the same columns. I've created one list with all the unique sample names (Samples_List) and then the actual list of all the dataframes (Samples_Dictionary). I'm trying to write a for loop that will cycle through these dataframes and automatically remove outliers. Where I'm getting stuck though is in calling the same column names for each dataframe in the for loop.

Here's a very simplified example:

```
Samples_List = names(Samples_Dictionary)
mean<- NULL
std<-NULL

for (x in Samples_List){
  mean[x]<-mean(Samples_Dictionary[x]$diameter)
  sd[x]<-sd(Samples_Dictionary[x]$diameter)}

# mean[A]<-mean(Samples_Dictionary$A$diameter works fine when not in the 
# loop but I can't seem to figure out how to work around the double '$'
```

Any suggestions or links to this if it's already been posted would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're using inconsistent names - `Samples_List` and `Samples_Dictionary`. Assuming the dictionary one is right, I would suggest `sample_means = sapply(Sample_List, \(x) mean(x$diameter))` and `sample_sds = sapply(Sample_List, \(x) sd(x$diameter))`.

Comment: Hi Gregor, I edited the description to hopefully clarify this. Samples_List is just all the unique names of samples within the list of dataframes (Samples_Dictionary).

Comment: It would be great to include the code `Samples_List = names(Samples_Dictionary)` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using inconsistent names - `Samples_List` and `Samples_Dictionary`. I'll assume the dictionary name is correct.

This is a great use-case for `sapply` or `lapply` - you're doing the same thing to each item of a list, returning a single result.  I would suggest:

```
sample_means = sapply(Samples_Dictionary, \(x) mean(x$diameter))
sample_sds = sapply(Samples_Dictionary, \(x) sd(x$diameter))
```

If you do want to use a `for` loop, you need to use `[[` to access a single item of a `list`. `Samples_Dictionary[x]` is a `list` of one data frame. `Samples_Dictionary[[x]]` is that one data frame.

```
Sample_List = names(Samples_Dictionary)
## it's a good habit to pre-allocate vectors to the right length when possible
sample_means = numeric(length(Samples_Dictionary)) |> setNames(Sample_List)
sample_sds = numeric(length(Samples_Dictionary)) |> setNames(Sample_List)


for(nm in Sample_List) {
  sample_means[nm] = mean(Samples_Dictionary[[nm]]$diameter)
  sample_sds[nm] = sd(Samples_Dictionary[[nm]]$diameter)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response Gregor! The last section showing the following was exactly what I was looking for:        for(nm in Sample_List) {
  sample_means[nm] = mean(Samples_Dictionary[[nm]]$diameter)
  sample_sds[nm] = sd(Samples_Dictionary[[nm]]$diameter) 
}